# Uploading files to EC2 Windows instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, upload

I've created an instance of a Windows Server 2008 AMI at Amazon EC2. I now need to upload some installation files to it.

One way to do this would be to activate the FTP server in Windows, set up an account and use that to upload files.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe some way to upload directly to an EBS?

Comment: What o/s is running on the machine where you have the installation files ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the copy/paste method with remote desktop, it is quick and dirty for sure.  Just make sure not to copy anything else on your clipboard while the data is uploading...it will cancel the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is the best way - via FTP server in Windows.

EBS is raw block storage that needs to be initialized by your EC2 instance, and accessed via your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like something a little more secure, consider CopSSH to enable SFTP transfers to your Windows instances:

http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/2008/08/21/ssh-sftp-for-windows-2008-server-using-c

Answer (score 0):

I usually use RDP's ability to map drives from the client, and then execute:

`robocopy \\tsclient\C\path\to\my\files c:\MyTempFolder FileToCopy.exe`